# add element to beginning of array with recursion and without any external libraries

Tags: c++, recursion

I want to add an element to the start of the array recursively. I want to push every element to the right and add one at the front. But there is weird output with this code if 0 or 1 is the array size. How should I change it?

```
void addelement(int arr[], int element, int pos, int size){
    if (size > pos){
        arr[size+1] = arr[size];
        addelement(arr, element, pos, size-1);
    }
    else{
        arr[pos] = element;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```cpp
void addElement(int arr[], int element, size_t pos, size_t size)
{
    // Avoid segfaults and undefined behavior
    // in case of empty array or out-of-bounds pos
    if (size == 0 || pos < 0 || size <= pos)
        return;
    
    size_t lastIndex(size-1);
    if (pos == lastIndex)
        arr[pos] = element;
    else
    {
        arr[lastIndex] = arr[lastIndex-1];
        addElement(arr, element, pos, lastIndex);
    }
}
```

I don't really understand why you want to go with recursion here though, so here is the same code using a reverse `for` loop:

```cpp
void addElement(int arr[], int element, size_t pos, size_t size)
{
    // Avoid segfault and undefined behavior
    if (size == 0 || pos < 0 || size <= pos)
        return;

    for (size_t i(size-1); i > pos; --i)
        arr[i] = arr[i-1];
    arr[pos] = element;
}
```

Now C-style arrays aren't the safest, I would use a `std::array` or a `std::vector` instead. For example:

```cpp
#include <array>

template <size_t N>
void addElement(std::array<int, N>& arr, int element, size_t pos)
{
    // Avoid segfault and undefined behavior
    if (N == 0 || pos < 0 || N <= pos)
        return;

    for (size_t i(N-1); i > pos; --i)
        arr[i] = arr[i-1];
    arr[pos] = element;
}
```

Please do keep in mind that arrays aren't best suited for this kind of computation, as they involve lots of copying: there is always a `arr[index] = arr[index-1]` lying somewhere. I recommend using something like a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) instead.